# JQuery validation functions firing on page load and throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background**

I have a form with a bunch of different input fields. I am using some `jquery functions` to validate the input fields on `keyup`.

Each one of the functions return true or false based on the response of the functions when the `keyup event` fires off.

These functions look like this,

**Example 1**

```
// First Name
var validate_first_name = function(first_name){
  var pattern =  /^[a-zA-Z'\s]{2,35}$/;
  var is_first_name_valid = false;
  if(first_name.match(pattern) != null){
    is_first_name_valid = true;
  }
  return is_first_name_valid;
}

$(document).on("keyup", "#first_name", function(){
  var input_val = $(this).val();
  var is_success = validate_first_name(input_val);
  if(!is_success){
    $('#first_name_val').addClass('fa-close').removeClass('fa-user-o').removeClass('fa-check');
  } else {
    $('#first_name_val').addClass('fa-check').removeClass('fa-user-o').removeClass('fa-close');
  }
});
```

**Problem**

I have a large amount of these functions and I want to disable the **`submit button`** till each one of these functions **`returns true`**.

**What I Tried**

I have tried a few variations of this following solution which either disables the button and won't ever enable it, or does not ever disable the button. I also tried moving the functions outside of the

`$(document).ready(function() {}`

I believe this solution causes an error because it tries to check the value of

```
    validate_first_name function
```

before it's `keypup event` fires off.

**Error**

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match'
>   of undefined
>       at validate_first_name (customer-primary.js:87)
>       at validate (customer-primary.js:365)

**Example 2**

```
// Check Validation or Disable Submit Button
function validate(){
    if (validate_first_name()       === true &&
        validate_last_name()        === true ){
        $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
    }
}

validate();
    $(
      '#first_name',
      '#last_name'
    ).change(validate);
}); // End Document Ready Function
```

Comment: Good god, if only every question on SO looked like this.

Comment: @JordanS thanks man! haha I appreciate you saying that.

Comment: should    $(
      '#first_name',
      '#last_name'
    ). be $("#first_name, #last_name").change ?  In jquery, the second argument is a scoping argument

Comment: Those are the ID's of the input fields. Also I was just trying to show some example of what I have tried. I have not go anything to actually work. If you have a better way of doing this logically I would be happy to see it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using callback functions to set something up else where in your page where they might not be finished when you finre the validate at the beginning?

Comment: I am sorry man but that did not make much sense to me. I am doing two separate things. I am validating each input field on key up. Which is example 1. Then I am validating that each input field evaluates to the return of the functions in example 1, by using the functions in example 2. Example one returns true or false and based on that I show the user some icons to show them if they filled out the input field right or wrong.

Comment: If the examples in 2 are confusing to you, and you have a way to do this that you do not find confusing, please let me know. You don't have to use my examples in 2. It was just were my brain is at but I realize it has a problem because it tries to evaluate each input field before they are all complete.

Comment: Oh I think I know what your asking. The key up function fires while they are typing. This is just to show the a check mark in the input field to signal to them that the data they entered is correct. As they type and the function runs it either returns true if regex passes, then I show icon check mark. Or false and then I show a X icon. So there is no callbacks needed. Each input field is checked independently while the user types. I left out all of the other functions to make it easier to read. All the functions are the same so there was no need to add them all to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Validate = function(form, elements) {

  /* PS: checkValid -> checks all the elements are valid */
  /* check if pattern matches and call checkValid */
  var validate = function(pattern, checkValid) {
    return function() {
      if (!this.value.match(pattern)) {
        /* remove 'valid' classes and add 'invalid' classes */
        this.classList.add('invalid');
        this.classList.remove('valid');
        this.valid = false;
      } else {
        /* 'reverse' add valid classes */
        this.classList.remove('invalid');
        this.classList.add('valid');
        this.valid = true;
      }
      checkValid();
    };
  };

  /* get the form with jquery */
  var $form = $(form);

  /* get the first button in form */
  var xButton = $form[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  xButton.disabled = true;

  /* check if all elements are valid */
  var checkValid = function() {
    var xFormValid = true;
    /* if one of the xElements / inputs is not valid */
    for (var key in elements) {
      if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var xElement = $form[0].elements[key];
        if (xElement.valid !== true) {
          xFormValid = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (xFormValid) {
      xButton.disabled = false;
    } else {
      xButton.disabled = true;
    }
  };
  /* each element in form */
  for (var key in elements) {
    if (elements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var xElement = $form[0].elements[key];
      var pattern = elements[key];

      /* set onkey up to validate(pattern, checkValidated) */
      xElement.onkeyup = validate(pattern, checkValid);
    }
  }
};

/* <form id="form1"> */
Validate('#form1', {
  /* <input name="firstName"> */
  firstName: /^[a-zA-Z'\s]{2,35}$/,
  /* <input name="lastName"> */
  lastName: /^[a-zA-Z'\s]{2,35}$/,
  /* <input name="email"> */
  email: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
});

Validate('#form2', {
  first_name: /^[a-zA-Z'\s]{2,35}$/,
  last_name: /^[a-zA-Z'\s]{2,35}$/,
});
```

```css
.valid,
.invalid:active,
.invalid:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.invalid,
.invalid:active,
.invalid:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

button:disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <p>
    <label>FIRST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>LAST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>EMAIL</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </p>
</form>

<hr>

<form id="form2">
  <p>
    <label>FIRST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>LAST NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Sp your suggestion is that I rewrite the hundreds of validation functions in this application? I am kinda confused. My problem here is that I have a large application with a bunch of functions like the ones in example 1. I need to come up with logic to disable input till they all evaluate to true. Writing a bunch of new functions in this project is not an option.

Comment: i pressed save / publish accidentally

Comment: Is this what you meant ?

Comment: And you want something like Validate('form', {name: {pattern: '...', validClasses: '...', invalidClasses: '...'}, ...}) ?